# Why is Type.GetType throwing "Collection was modified; enumeration may not execute"?

Tags: c#, .net

The following line of code appears in one of the libraries we are using:

```
var microsoftDataSqlClientConnectionStringBuilderType =
    Type.GetType("Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder, Microsoft.Data.SqlClient", throwOnError: false);
```

Sometimes, when running this code through NUnit (net472), we see the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException : Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
Stacktrace
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName)
   at System.Type.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError)
```

Why would `Type.GetType` throw this exception?

Comment: Which version of .Net is this?

Comment: Really weird, I suspect a bug. Relevant code for `RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName` is a QCall, and the C++ side is [here](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/vm/runtimehandles.cpp)

Comment: Did you check the call stack?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski do you mean something separate from the call stack I posted?

Comment: @Charlieface this is on .NET Framework 4.8 (release key 528049).

Comment: Why is there a vote to close this question? Anything I can do to provide more clarity?

Comment: My psychic debugger says that this exception was actually thrown in an event handler, like AppDomain.AssemblyResolve.  Try debugging it by forcing the debugger to stop on the first-chance exception.

Comment: It's not a static constructor that's throwing I don't think. @HansPassant But why does that not show up in the stack trace, does the Resolve callback not have a transition back to managed code? *EDIT* **Indeed, looks like a failing resolver does exactly that**

Comment: If you can't use first-chance exceptions, check `exception.InnerException.StackTrace` @HansPassant What I mean to say is that it catches the exception and re-throws it's own with an InnerException, so you don't see the trace

Comment: @mjwills I'd love to have a minimal reproduction too. Unfortunately, this error occurs transiently and currently we've only seen in our CI pipeline. I have not been able to reproduce reliably or locally. My hope with this question was to gain some kind of lead/insight into what might cause this which could provide some direction for our investigation.

Comment: @Charlieface you are correct that this code is not being called from a static constructor, it is being called from an NUnit test setup method. **Also to confirm, are you saying that an AssemblyResolve event handler would or would not trigger this behavior**? I don't see any such handlers in our code, although perhaps the NUnit runner registers one?

Comment: I can't say for sure that that is what it is, but it does appear to have the same effect. As i said, use first-chance exception breakpoints, or check the InnerException stacktrace